# SQL Server 2008 Script Changes from Database Diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, scripting, database-diagrams

I have a database diagram which I have made several changes to using SSMS, however instead of committing the changes I want to generate a SQL script to apply them instead. Is there a simple way to do this using the GUI?

I have done a Google search, but could not find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More Google searching did not help, but after fiddling around with SSMS I managed to figure it out. Thought I'd answer my own question for anyone else who might stumble across this.

To script all of the changes at once, simply right-click a blank area of the diagram and click 'Select All' (or press Ctrl+A). Then right-click one of the selected tables and choose 'Generate Change Script...' at the bottom.